# Custom List from webservice to a List box in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, web-services

I have a web service that fetches data from a database table and adds it to a custom list, and I now need to send that data into a listbox in a windows form, but I don't seem to be able to do it, the web service is referenced in the winform app,and I'm using another methods from that same web service in that app,so I don't think its a problem with the reference or the web service itself, I just can't add the data into the listbox, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

The method:

```
public List<SLA_ClassLibrary.SLA_Class.ReadAtm> ReadAtm()
{
    var AtmReadList = new List<SLA_ClassLibrary.SLA_Class.ReadAtm>();
    using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SLAdb"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (Conn)
        {
            Conn.Open();
            string SQLReadAtm = "Select * from ATM;";
            SqlCommand ReadAtmCmd = new SqlCommand(SQLReadAtm, Conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = ReadAtmCmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                AtmReadList.Add(new SLA_ClassLibrary.SLA_Class.ReadAtm
                {
                    idatm = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("IDATM")),
                    District_Region = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("District_Region")),
                    Local = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Local")),
                    IsUp = reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("IsUp"))
                });
            }
         }
        return AtmReadList;
    }
}
```

This is the code for the winform regarding the method

```
ServiceConsumer.UsersMethodsSoapClient CheckAtms = new ServiceConsumer.UsersMethodsSoapClient();
listBox1.Items.Add(CheckAtms.ReadAtm());
```

And the class that I'm using to create the custom list

```
public class ReadAtm
{
    public int idatm { get; set; }
    public string District_Region { get; set; }
    public string Local { get; set; }
    public bool IsUp { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You added a list as an item of `ListBox`. Instead you should set it as its `DataSource` this way `listBox1.DataSource = CheckAtms.ReadAtm();` and then set `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` to desired properties.

Comment: But can I do that with a method that returns a custom list? @RezaAghaei

Comment: Yes,you can any collection of data to assign DataSource